# swift convert Range<Int> to [Int]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, int, range

how to convert Range to Array

I tried:

```
let min = 50
let max = 100
let intArray:[Int] = (min...max)
```

get error `Range<Int> is not convertible to [Int]`

I also tried:

```
let intArray:[Int] = [min...max]
```

and

```
let intArray:[Int] = (min...max) as [Int]
```

they don't work either.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

You need to *create* an `Array<Int>` using the `Range<Int>` rather than *cast*ing it.

```
let intArray: [Int] = Array(min...max)
```

Comment: thanks, I just figured it while you sent your answer

Answer (score 47):

Put the Range in the init.

```
let intArray = [Int](min...max)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @MrBeardsley

Answer (score 18):

I figured it out:

```
let intArray = [Int](min...max)
```

Giving credit to someone else.

Answer (score 15):

Use `map`

```
let min = 50
let max = 100
let intArray = (min...max).map{$0}
```

Comment: adding why it works would be beneficial for people who are reading this kind of questions. For example stating that it creates a CoutableClosedRange which implements Sequence protocol, therefore map is possible and it yields a new int lazily when performing map operation.
Some background knowledge is always good

Comment: The other answers are interesting but this one actually answers the question. Big up.

Answer (score 15):

do:

```
let intArray = Array(min...max)
```

This should work because `Array` has an initializer taking a `SequenceType` and `Range` conforms to `SequenceType`.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting that you cannot (at least, with Swift 3 and Xcode 8) use `Range<Int>` object directly:

```
let range: Range<Int> = 1...10
let array: [Int] = Array(range)  // Error: "doesn't conform to expected type 'Sequence'"
```

Therefore, as it was mentioned earlier, you need to manually "unwrap" you range like:

```
let array: [Int] = Array(range.lowerBound...range.upperBound)
```

I.e., you *can* use literal only.

Comment: The reason for this is because Ranges aren't Collections. The distinction between Range and Countable Range is that the latter can be iterated over by an Integer value. For that reason Countable Range is a collection type in swift but range is not.

Comment: That's right, and I wasn't expecting this, i.e. two different range classes. Probably due to Pythonic interpretation of `range()`.

Answer (score 3):

Since Swift 3/Xcode 8 there is a `CountableRange` type, which can be handy:

```
let range: CountableRange<Int> = -10..<10
let array = Array(range)
print(array)
// prints: 
// [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

It can be used directly in `for`-`in` loops:

```
for i in range {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: This is (now) the correct way to handle the task. Also works in Swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement ClosedRange & Range instance intervals with reduce() in functions like this.

```
func sumClosedRange(_ n: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    return n.reduce(0, +)
}
sumClosedRange(1...10) // 55
```

```
func sumRange(_ n: Range<Int>) -> Int {
    return n.reduce(0, +)
}
sumRange(1..<11) // 55
```