# malloc error when generating huge random number

Tags: swift, largenumber, random-seed, int64

I want to get a random element from 0 to a huge number (2^31).

I tried creating an `Array` from such a `Range` (so I can use Swift's  `Array.randomElement`), as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103282/swift-convert-rangeint-to-int):

`let myArray: [Int64] = [Int64](0...4294967292)`

Which compiles, but crashes with:

> MyPoject(1569,0x100cc2f40) malloc: can't allocate region mach_vm_map(size=34359738368) failed (error code=3)
>   MyProject(1569,0x100cc2f40) malloc: set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Of course, I can write a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886320/int64-creating-a-number-range) to create the array, but that smells, especially because the array will be the exact same every time.

Does Swift provide a better solution?

Comment: Such an array would require about 32 GB memory – how much does your compute have?

Comment: What do you want to do to the array that you can't do with a `Range`?

Comment: @DaniSpringer: Indeed. – You should tell us your *real* problem.

Comment: `ClosedRange` also has a `randomElement` method.

Comment: Did you consider using `Int64.max` constant instead of the ugly magical value?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to roll back the last edit – it removed the context of the existing answers, making them unclear for future readers of this Q&A.

Comment: @MartinR agreed, thanks. I was trying to reduce noise. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message

> malloc: can't allocate region mach_vm_map(size=34359738368)

tells that the runtime could not allocate 32GB memory – that is what an array of 4294967292 64-bit integers would require at

```
let myArray: [Int64] = [Int64](0...4294967292)
```

But there is no need to create an array for that purpose. As of Swift 4.2 you can simply call

```
let rnd = Int64.random(in: 0...4294967292)
// or
let rnd = Int64.random(in: 0..<4294967293)
```

using one of the

```
static func random(in range: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self
static func random(in range: Range<Self>) -> Self
```

methods of the [`FixedWidthInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger) protocol.

Finally note that `4294967292` is not `2^31 = 2147483648` – if the intention is to create a random number in the range from `0` (inclusive) to `2^31` (exclusive) then

```
let rnd = Int32.random(in: 0...Int32.max)
```

would to the trick.

Comment: Does it make sense to add the explanation of the memory error to the question, as perhaps one can have such a question even whilst knowing the meaning of that error?

Comment: @DaniSpringer: It is not entirely clear to me what you are suggesting, but explanations should be in answers, not in questions. However, you could change the title to *“malloc error when generating huge random number”* to distinguish it from other questions about random numbers, and to make it easier to find for others with a similar problem.

Comment: If you want non-repeating random values from 0 to 2^31 its a more complex problem. My usual approach of building an array of all possible values and removing one random value at a time until you have the desired number of values won't work because it requires too much memory, as the OP discovered. You'd have to add random values to a set until you had the desired number of entries, then convert the set into an array.

Answer (score 3):

`ClosedRange` also has a `randomElement` method in Swift 4.2:

```
print((0...4294967292).randomElement()!)
```

Note that you said you want a random number between 0 and 2^31, but you used `1...4294967292` instead of `0...4294967292` in your example.

Comment: Ah it does, that's good to know. And wow, **SO** you did it in under 20 mins  Yeah the truth is 0 and 1 are both good (which is why I didn't realize I was inconsistent), because my idea was I can add 1 to the result later.